# SharePoint 2013 "Maps"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-addin

I've been asked to create a page that would basically be like a dashboard containing various statistical information.  I am in the process of sorting that aspect out but one of the requests is to map the location of our cliental using their addresses.  Is there a way in SharePoint 2013 to create some kind of web app that would look at the information contained in a file and then show pins based on the information?  An added bonus would be to create a second "layer" that can be turned on or off and would alter the icon based on a code that related to the type of client.

Thanks for any and all advice/ideas!

Comment: Can you store address information in SharePoint list? If yes, you can use JSOM to pull the addresses and use google maps api to display them as pins on the map. You can use different pin icons based on client type. See this Google api reference https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*attention SE SP admin: I'm referring to some other software here, I'm not sure of the correct process for doing this.  My apologies if I have broken a rule*

Hi,

You could also try some software specifically for mapping.  Examples of mapping free software I've used in the past are MangoMaps or Cartodb [link to Cartodb](https://carto.com/).  You just need data in .csv format and you can upload it.  I was able to get the maps I made to display on a Sharepoint page.  I ended up using Cartodb in the end.

The 'alternativeto' website can suggest other mapping software should you decide you want to explore this further.  Don't use QGIS or PostGIS as they are for the hardcore GIS professionals.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  Although this solution would work I am unable to use it as a result of the type of information we want to map.  I'm quickly learning that the "free" way of doing this requires the data to be public :(

Comment: Yes, Cartodb used to be free, even for private maps, but they have changed their policy now.  I've not used Mangomaps for a long time, so I'm not sure about them.  You might find another company that provides free, private mapping software.  Stack Exchange has a GIS forum too, so perhaps search there for free mapping software.